# Android Getting current location failed

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

with this function I get longitude = 0 and latitude = 0
I don't know where the problem is

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        //Getting longitude and latitude
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        //moving the map to location
        moveMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged? Your problem is either `location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);` or `getLongitude();`

Answer (score 1):

Do this in the `onConnected()` callback provided by Google API Client, which is called when the client is ready. The following code snippet illustrates the request and a simple handling of the response:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
...
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I did not understand, I have a button when I click on it marks my position and it gives me the cordonéée in a toast, and now mLatitudeText mlongitudeText are what kind? In onconnceted I did call getCurrentLocation ();

Comment: Is the location that your getting correct ? I mean in the toast.

Comment: No ,i get long = 0 lat= 0

Comment: Check for the values which you got in the `onconnected` method and see if its correct.

Comment: 404 not found ! , i taked the code from this tutorial [https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-google-maps-tutorial-google-maps-android-api/#]

Comment: This is the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

Comment: Something similar in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700374/trying-to-get-current-location-through-onconnected-method)

Comment: that's what I did but it returns me long 0  lat 0

Comment: about this question. he added an "if" but my procedure takes me long =0 lat = 0 suddenly it does not work!